# How to remove an HTML append after a certain time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Currently I have a page that uses jquery and php to upload info, next it should display the recently added items for a few seconds and then fade them away but leave the div for the recently added items.
  the items are being displayed in

```
 '<ul id="responds" >

  '</ul>
```

as list items, whenever the insert is successful 
 with this ajax request

```
 '$.ajax({
  type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
  url: "response.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
  dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
  data:myData, //
  success:function(result){
     $("#responds").delay(10000).fadeIn();
    $("#responds").append("<li class='res'>"+result+"</li>");
           $('.res').remove();
          $("#proyecto").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#departamento").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#tipo_activo").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#modelo").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#numero_serie").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#marca").val(''); //empty text field on successful
          $("#numero_remision").val(''); //empty text field on successful
    $("#cuenta_sap").val(''); //empty text field on successful
    $("#ubicacion").val(''); //empty text field on successful
    $("#nombre").val(''); //empty text field on successful
    $("#codigo_centro_beneficio").val(''); //empty text field on successful
    $("#FormSubmit").show(); //show submit button
    $("#LoadingImage").hide(); //hide loading image'
```

basiclly my question is how would i do to append 'res'  after an insert and then fade it out after a while, and if I add another entry, give it the same fade out time to it but not aftecting the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by creating actual jQuery objects, then just remove them again in a timeout or a callback function, something like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "response.php",
    dataType: "text",
    data: myData,
    success: function (result) {
        var li = $('<li />', {
            'class' : 'res',
            text    : result
        });

        $("#responds").append(li).delay(10000).fadeIn();

        setTimeout(function() {
            li.fadeOut(function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }, 15000)

        .... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the append a unique ID, and create a timeout that looks for the id and removes it.